# Date picker not working inside modal jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datepicker

I'm using this date field; on simple html page it is working

```js
if ($('.datepicker').length) {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: 0
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" integrity="sha512-ELV+xyi8IhEApPS/pSj66+Jiw+sOT1Mqkzlh8ExXihe4zfqbWkxPRi8wptXIO9g73FSlhmquFlUOuMSoXz5IRw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-57oZ/vW8ANMjR/KQ6Be9v/+/h6bq9/l3f0Oc7vn6qMqyhvPd1cvKBRWWpzu0QoneImqr2SkmO4MSqU+RpHom3Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<input class="datepicker" type="text" name="pickup_date" id="pickup_date" value="" placeholder="Select Date">
```

but on modal it is not working

i have tried

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('.date').datepicker();
});

$(document).on('click', "#openbtn", function( ){
  
  $('#exampleModal').modal('show');

  setTimeout(function () {
      
    if($('.datepicker').length){
      $( '.datepicker' ).datepicker();
    }
  }, 500);
```

but it is not working

Comment: don't use jQuery modal, use real HTML modal `<dialog>`

Comment: @MisterJojo thanks but as per design I have to use bootstrap modal can you pls let me know how to bond date picker when modal is opened

Comment: So what ? nothing prohibits using HTML modal dialog and Boostrap

Comment: @user3653474 provide an example of it not working using the modal.

Comment: *but on modal it is not working* - which modal?  Your comments suggest bootstrap modal, but why not jquery-ui modal?  Or some other of the 1000s of div-based modals (before `<dialog>` was an option).  Bootstrap and jquery-ui don't mix well as they have conflicting css class names.   Can you update your snipper to include which version of bootstrap you are using and how you create the "modal" with the datepicker on it (eg loading HTML via ajax for the modal content?)  if using ajax, provide a mock that provides the html.

Answer (score 0):

hope this can help

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<script>

    
    $(document).ready(function() {
    
    if ($('.datepicker').length) {
      $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        minDate: 0
      });
    }
    
    $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
    
});

</script>




<!-- Trigger button to open the modal -->
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Open Modal
</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="exampleModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      This is the modal content.
    
     <input class="datepicker" type="text" name="pickup_date" id="pickup_date" value="" placeholder="Select Date">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>






    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" integrity="sha512-ELV+xyi8IhEApPS/pSj66+Jiw+sOT1Mqkzlh8ExXihe4zfqbWkxPRi8wptXIO9g73FSlhmquFlUOuMSoXz5IRw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-57oZ/vW8ANMjR/KQ6Be9v/+/h6bq9/l3f0Oc7vn6qMqyhvPd1cvKBRWWpzu0QoneImqr2SkmO4MSqU+RpHom3Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```